# black screen while running corona sdk(i am using composer)

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

So once i save it and click launch the screen is black no scenes are showing

can someone figure out what is wrong with this and know how to correctly fix it.
I'll be gladly if someone can.

Thank You.

**This is my Main.lua-**

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()

-- your code goes here...

composer.gotoScene("menu")
```

**THIS is my Menu.lua-**

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- All code outside of the listener functions will only be executed ONCE unless "composer.removeScene()" is called.
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- local forward references should go here

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-- "scene:create()"
function scene:create( event )
   local sceneGroup = self.view

   local background = display.newImageRect( "background.png", 730, 400 )
   sceneGroup:insert( background )

end


-- "scene:show()"
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen).
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is now on screen.
        -- Insert code here to make the scene come alive.
        -- Example: start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.
        print("menu")
    end
end


-- "scene:hide()"
function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen).
        -- Insert code here to "pause" the scene.
        -- Example: stop timers, stop animation, stop audio, etc.
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called immediately after scene goes off screen.
    end
end


-- "scene:destroy()"
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Called prior to the removal of scene's view ("sceneGroup").
    -- Insert code here to clean up the scene.
    -- Example: remove display objects, save state, etc.
end


-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Comment: Please show your config.lua and build.settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the possible problem could be the path of the image and the scene.

If your are using the above code then all your background image and menu.lua should be in the main folder and not in any sub folder first check these two things.

Then i think your not giving the x and y values of the image,

background .x = display.contentWidth/2
background .y = display.contentHeight/2

These are possible problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the beginning of your menu.lua

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()
local background
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- All code outside of the listener functions will only be executed ONCE unless "composer.removeScene()" is called.
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- local forward references should go here

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-- "scene:create()"
function scene:create( event )
   local sceneGroup = self.view

   background = display.newImageRect( "background.png", 730, 400 )
   background.x = display.contentCenterX
   background.y = display.contentCenterY
   sceneGroup:insert( background )

end
```

You need to declare the background image as local in your scene file (menu.lua), not local in your create function

Comment: okay so I re-edited the menu.lua, now once I launched it, Shows up black screen still. Basically nothing is coming up. The only this is taking effect is the statusbar being shown or not shown.

Comment: ok, I added code to center the image in the screen. Also you could say if you have any errors in the console. I tried the code with my own background image and it's working.

Comment: I have no errors in the console. May I please see how your "config.lua" and "bulid.settings" is setup, because i think maybe that's it.

Comment: It is wrong to say that background should not be local. As long as it is inserted into scene, it can be local or global, doesn't matter.